# Do I need to learn C++ to use Open GL?

Tags: c++, opengl

Do I need to learn C++ to use Open GL?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Not at all! Due to its simple C API, OpenGL has bindings available for [Java](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/), [Python](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/), [Ruby](http://ruby-opengl.rubyforge.org/), and just about [any](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Opengl) [other](http://glcaml.sourceforge.net/) [language](http://luagl.sourceforge.net/) you can think of!

Answer (score 7):

OpenGL is a C API. There are bindings for other languages but samples in books and tutorials tend to be written in C.

Because of this knowing C can help. You definitely don't have to learn C++ to use OpenGL though.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. In fact, OpenGL is native C.
There is JOGL, which is a Java wrapper.
OpenGL ES, which is for the iPhone. I believe this is in Obj-C as well as C/C++. [Not sure, think so]
I think things like PyGame end up as OpenGL in the end, and they're done in Python.

But for raw OpenGL for the PC, the only choices I know of are C, C++, or Java.

Comment: Obj-C is a strict superset of plain C. The OpenGL ES API is a pure C API, so the Obj- part of it is irrelevant.

Comment: Apologies for that. I took them to be different languages.

Comment: Pygame by default does not end up as OpenGL in the end; SDL's default rendering model is CPU-side framebuffers. You can use Pygame with OpenGL, but none of the core Pygame documentation covers how to do it.

Comment: Pyglet however is a Python library that has much of the functionality of Pygame but which does actually use OpenGL for rendering.

Comment: OpenGL-ES is not only for iPhone..