# Is it possible to use OpenGL purely with C instead of C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, c

Is it possible to use OpenGL purely with C instead of C++? I am wanting to make sure there won't be any problems with my using C and not C++. OpenGL does not depend on any C++ libraries right?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL, `Written in: C` - I almost feel like saying UTSE, but that doesn't seem in the spirit of SE.

Comment: @Daniel It might be in the spirit of SE when the downvote button says "This question does not show any research effort" on the alt-text.

Comment: The research effort was spent looking at C++ tutorials and seeing none for C.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to learn C++ to use Open GL?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1838/do-i-need-to-learn-c-to-use-open-gl)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, in fact OpenGL is a C library. You can perfectly use it with C.

Comment: Note that the normative standard documents do not use the syntax of the C headers/bindings in the text, and explicitly says that implementations are free to use any kind of naming convention. OpenGL import libraries are probably in C due to historical reasons and due to that C is the language that FFI or interop functionality tends to consume. Technically, a vendor could deploy an OpenGL library in any language, but by convention the OS/vendor interface is the common C one.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL can be used in C. Some libraries can't, though. For example if you want to use [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/) you will have to use C++ instead of C.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is a C library, which means that it's made with and for C, so of course it works with C. The reason why it also works with C++ is because C++ is actually nothing else than C with some things added so any C code is also valid in C++. So OpenGL uses C code which is also valid in C++, and it doesn't use anything that is specific for C++.